# Is it possible to get list of all called function by clicking on an element

Tags: javascript

I am facing a problem, I am updating a website which has many many javascript functions for example a selectbox has an onchange event listener. By selecting a value a function will be called and that in turn call other functions and those function call others.

Is there a possiblility to get a list of all these functions?

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome developer tools provides that. Select the item and check Event Listeners at the right.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a breakpoint in firebug in the "deepest" function possible. WHen the script engine hits that breakpoint, you will have access to the call stack, which shows all the functions that have been called.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don’t use `"use strict";` you can use the `arguments.callee.caller` to figure out the calling function.  To get one level higher, use `arguments.callee.caller.arguments.callee.caller`, etc., or better yet, write a recursive function.

Check out Amir Harel’s [Stack Trace](http://www.amirharel.com/2010/01/25/using-caller-and-callee-for-stack-trace/) implementation for a more elaborate example.

**Update:** or check out http://stacktracejs.org/, which is a *lot* more elaborate!